# How do I extract the fewest characters between two words?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I am trying to find the shortest character sequence between the words "I" and "disagree" (not case-sensitive). I've read through all the similar questions on SO, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. Here is an example sentence that is causing me grief:

```
As an American, I must disagree with you.
```

And here is my best guess as to a regex pattern:

```
I(.*?)disagree
```

I want to capture just the **" must "**, but instead, I'm capturing the longer string, **"can, I must "**. I am hoping not to have to specify that the "I" must be followed by something else, like a space. Because, then I wouldn't capture anything in a sentence like, **"I'll disagree with that."** I also don't want to insist that the "I" be capitalized. Basically, I just want the least-greedy match possible. This site is one of the places I'm using to verify the solution:

http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=I%28.*%3F%29%20disagree&input=As%20an%20American%2C%20I%20must%20disagree%20with%20you.

Comment: Use `\b` to require a *word boundary* around the captured part. Then collect all matches and pick the shortest?

Comment: Is this an actual use case?

Comment: If the input is `"I kinda disagree"`, do you want `" kinda "`, or `"nda "`?

Comment: Excellent example of a case I hadn't thought of. I would want to see " kinda ". Still, my concern wasn't so much about my approach to finding intermediate words, it was that the way I had chosen wasn't giving the results I expected. I've used this pattern so many times... I spent hours debugging before I finally started to question my regex pattern. I'll probably use the word boundary suggestions to solve the actual problem, but the negative lookahead method is the behavior I was expecting.

Comment: Gumbo, this is an actual use case. I am a grad student working on automatically classifying sentences as expressing agreement or disagreement. I'm looking for the minimal lexical patterns that are commonly used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is to use a [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(I)(((?!\1).)*?) disagree
```

See **[demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%28I%29%28%28%28%3F!%5C1%29.%29%2a%3F%29%20disagree&input=As%20an%20American%2C%20I%20must%20disagree%20with%20you.%0AAlso%2C%20I%20I-I-I%20I%27ll%20disagree%20with%20you.)** here.

Notice the group for the word in between is now `$2`. If you don't want that, you can repeat the 1st word:

```
I((?:(?!I).)*?) disagree
```

<sub>But I'd say the first version is easier to maintain, specially if the word is [bigger](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%28American%29%28%28%28?!%5C1%29.%29%2a?%29%20disagree&input=As%20an%20American%20flag,%20so%20American%20I%20must%20disagree%20with%20you.).</sub>

Comment: All these answers are very helpful. This negative lookahead approach, however, is more exactly what I was trying to accomplish with my regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundaries (`\b`):

```
/\bi(.*?)\bdisagree/i
```

- case insensitive
- matches `I`, but not `I'll` (the `'ll` will be part of the captured)

Comment: put a `\b` behind the I as well, or it will match any word beginning with an I. `\bI\b` will match both `I` in `I` and `I'll`.

Comment: Word boundaries will only work if, of course, the patterns in between are supposed to be only full words. If not, word boundaries [will not be general enough](http://goo.gl/u0C6qx).

Comment: Both true, otherwise `\s` will need to be used with some positive/negative lookbehinds

Comment: It -does- match `I` in `I'll`: [See here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%5CbI%5Cb(.*%3F)%5Cbdisagree&input=I%20must%20not%20disagree%20when%20something%20disagrees%20with%20independance%20disagree%20I'll%20disagree%20with%20you).

Comment: @Sumurai8: no it still matches `I` in the `I'll`, the `'ll` will be part of what's captured; the apostrophe `'` will mark a word-boundary

Comment: That was what I was saying. Your previous text claimed it would not match at all, which was incorrect.

Comment: @Sumurai8 the text is the same, I only added that the `'ll` will be captured to clarify that `I` is the matching word in both cases

Answer (score 1):

you need to use lookaround for regex, use this regex `(?<=[iI])(\W.*)(?=disagree)` and you will get only the word between I and disagree.

[Example here](http://regexr.com?35qr3)

Comment: JavaScript doesn’t support look-behind assertions.

Comment: but i try this in JEdit and this is work. I think these were fixed in JDK 1.6?